# Create custom map with roads, transport, etc

Tags: web-apps, maps

I have a large image from a game I play that I want to convert into a map with similar features to Google Maps and which can be displayed on my server using either the LAMP or WAMP environment if possible.

I would like the map to have the following features:

- Route finding (not 100% necessary but would be really nice)
- Show icons of shops, transport, etc.
- show overlays (not 100% necessary)
- Zoom in and out
- Mark pathways and roads
- Mark safe areas and other zones

I am hoping that Google has something hidden away that I haven't found yet, but anything that is user friendly would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) seems to solve this problem. Please look at [this](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) sample tutorial that addresses exactly your problem statement

I hope you have solved it already. If yes, please let me know the technology used.